# IF ELSE condition in stored procedure to include or exclude weekend data

Tags: sql-server

I need to amend a stored procedure in SQL Server.

It is currently fetching data from currency rates table in the database for dates excluding weekends. i.e Currency rates table has daily data for all currencies.

Now I need to add a condition, include an "Exclude Weekends" flag; when turned on, this flag would exclude weekends, and if turned off, it would show data for all days of the week.

Comment: So what is the issue then? Did you stuck with some specific problem? I hope you are not expecting people will do your urgent job ;)

Comment: I am not ablt to add the flag. say if exclude weekend = 0 then return data for all days from currency rates table. if exclude weekend =1, exclude saturday and sunday data. how do i put this logic

Comment: this code above is skipping all the days by 1 day each when excweekend is 1.  however i only wish to exclude sat and sunday

Comment: the way you've implemented `IF` condition is wrong. The correct syntax should be 
`IF <boolean expression> 
BEGIN 
 <your-scripts-to-perform> 
END`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach is to filter it at the end of the procedure, forget about the new `IF` conditions and use just a `WHERE` clause to filter it out something like,

```
SELECT  Date  , Weekname  ,Dayofweek, B.Value , B.currencyCode , B.currencyName  INTO #TEMP 
FROM @tempdatetable
WHERE (ExcWeekend=1 AND Dayofweek  NOT IN (1,7)) OR ExcWeekend=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options, let the loop stay as is and remove weekends from the list.  Or create a date lookup table.  Both assume you pass in a parameter @excludeWeekendFlag = 'N'.

```
--option 1:
    SELECT  Date  , Weekname  ,Dayofweek, B.Value , B.currencyCode , B.currencyName  INTO 
    #TEMP FROM @tempdatetable 
    CROSS JOIN  
    ( select A.Value , B.currencyCode , B.currencyName from #tempCurr A INNER JOIN 
    CURRENCY(NOLOCK) B ON A.Value =B.currency ) B 
    --- Exclude weekends
    WHERE (DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) != 7 AND DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) != 0 AND @ExcludeWeekends = 'Y') OR @ExcludeWeekends = 'N'
```

Another approach is to have a table filled with dates, and alongside each one have a type.  Like 0 weekday 1 weened 2 public holiday etc.

Good luck.